# Tests of stationarity in irregularly (unevenly) spaced time series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I need to do check if my time series data is stationary or not. However, the data is so irregular that cannot be transformed into evenly spaced. Any suggestion?

Comment: 1) plot it! 2) you can estimate a variogram, 1D-version, analogous to what is done in geostatistics, 3) look into continuous-time autoregressive models

Comment: See for instance https://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/E84BB1D4E1D2A8E48525706900694328/$File/rc23702.pdf  as a start